# Using LINQ to take the top 100 and bottom 100?

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to do something like this (below) but not sure if there is a formal/optimized syntax to do so?

```
.Orderby(i => i.Value1)
.Take("Bottom 100 & Top 100")
.Orderby(i => i.Value2);
```

basically, I want to sort by one variable, then take the top 100 and bottom 100, and then sort  those results by another variable.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does your list contain more than 200 items everytime or does it have to be considered that Top 100 and Bottom 100 could share the same list entries?

Comment: It could be better to write your own extension method with the name: `TakeLastAndFirst(number)`

Comment: What LINQ provider are you using? LINQ to Objects? LINQ to Entities? Something else?

Answer (score 32):

```
var sorted = list.OrderBy(i => i.Value);
var top100 = sorted.Take(100);
var last100 = sorted.Reverse().Take(100);
var result = top100.Concat(last100).OrderBy(i => i.Value2);
```

I don't know if you want `Concat` or `Union` at the end. `Concat` will combine all entries of both lists even if there are similar entries which would be the case if your original list contains less than 200 entries. `Union` would only add stuff from last100 that is not already in top100.

Some things that are not clear but that should be considered:

- If **list** is an `IQueryable` to a db, it probably is advisable to use `ToArray()` or `ToList()`, e.g.

  ```
  var sorted = list.OrderBy(i => i.Value).ToArray();
  ```

  at the beginning. This way only one query to the database is done while the rest is done in memory.
- The `Reverse` method is not optimized the way I hoped for, but it shouldn't be a problem, since ordering the list is the real deal here. For the record though, the skip method explained in other answers here is probably a little bit faster but needs to know the number of elements in **list**.
- If **list** would be a `LinkedList` or another class implementing `IList`, the `Reverse` method could be done in an optimized way.

Comment: It might be really big performance issue if we have `list` as a IQueryable to DB which returns thousands of records being expanded - I'm pretty sure that Reverse will read whole bunch of records from DB to operate. I think `list.Skip(list.Count() - 100).Take(100)` will be better instead of `reverse ... take`, even with additional query to `Count`

Comment: I was hoping Reverse would be optimized for certain types of IEnumerable like LinkedList for example. OP didnt tell so far what we are querying from. I would add a ToArray at the first line then to make it just a single query for the db.

Comment: Enumerating multiple times could be an issue if the list isn't in memory (e.g. IQueryable)

Comment: @T_D ToArray() won't be much help for 600K+ items, for example, in terms of performance.

Comment: This looks very inefficient. Unless I miss my guess, the sort will actually be executed twice (most Enumerable extensions are re-evaluated on every enumeration, and I believe `OrderBy` is no exception) and then the `Reverse` will have to buffer the entire sequence, which takes as much memory as just converting to a list (`ToList`). So you're getting the worst of all worlds, memory and running time. It would be better just to use two sorts, one `OrderBy` and `OrderByDescending`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use an extension method like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> TakeFirstAndLast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int count)
{
    var first = new List<T>();
    var last = new LinkedList<T>();
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (first.Count < count)
            first.Add(item);
        if (last.Count >= count)
            last.RemoveFirst();
        last.AddLast(item);
    }

    return first.Concat(last);
}
```

(I'm using a `LinkedList<T>` for `last` because it can remove items in `O(1)`)

You can use it like this:

```
.Orderby(i => i.Value1)
.TakeFirstAndLast(100)
.Orderby(i => i.Value2);
```

Note that it doesn't handle the case where there are less then 200 items: if it's the case, you will get duplicates. You can remove them using `Distinct` if necessary.

Comment: +1  I have also answered the question with extension method. But in my function I need total count of items in the Enumerable, to find the last N items. But, this doesn't need it.

Answer (score 5):

Take the top 100 and bottom 100 separately and union them:

```
var tempresults = yourenumerable.OrderBy(i => i.Value1);
var results = tempresults.Take(100);
results = results.Union(tempresults.Skip(tempresults.Count() - 100).Take(100))
                 .OrderBy(i => i.Value2);
```

Comment: `Union` will skip repeated records, you may need to use `Concat` instead

Comment: That would be based on OPs request. If he does not want duplicates, union would be ok.

Comment: I may be wrong, but op says top 100 & bottom 100. Which intuitively means I need 200 elements. Anyhow, let OP say :)

Comment: This does three sorting operations though, although I think only two are needed.

Comment: OP asked for top 100 (1 sort), bottom 100(2nd sort) and a sort on the results on a different element (3rd sort). So i think this is per his request.

Comment: Top 100 & bottom 100 can be taken from a list that only has been sorted once ;)

Comment: @T_D What would you think of my edit? I think it would work but it added a count.

Comment: The `Count()` will evaluate the entire sequence, so this is significantly slower than an imperative solution, and I believe might also throw an exception if there are fewer than 100 elements.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with in one statement also using this [`.Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549418%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) overload, if you have the number of elements available:

```
var elements = ...

var count = elements.Length; // or .Count for list

var result = elements
    .OrderBy(i => i.Value1)
    .Where((v, i) => i < 100 || i >= count - 100)
    .OrderBy(i => i.Value2)
    .ToArray();             // evaluate
```

Here's how it works:

```
| first 100 elements | middle elements | last 100 elements |
        i < 100        i < count - 100    i >= count - 100
```

Comment: Would work but Where would need to check all the entries instead of just taking first and last 100. So with super long lists that could lead to decreased performance

Comment: @T_D Not sure that it would take too long. It's just an enumerator, there are no side effects (that I know of).

Comment: @T_D The dominant operation here is sorting. So one additional linear lookup seems irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own **extension method** like `Take()`, `Skip()` and other methods from `Enumerable` class. It will take the numbers of elements and the total length in list as input. Then it will return first and last **N** elements from the sequence.

```
var result = yourList.OrderBy(x => x.Value1)
                     .GetLastAndFirst(100, yourList.Length)
                     .OrderBy(x => x.Value2)
                     .ToList();
```

Here is the extension method:

```
public static class SOExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetLastAndFirst<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> seq, int number, int totalLength
    )
    {
        if (totalLength < number*2) 
            throw new Exception("List length must be >= (number * 2)");

        using (var en = seq.GetEnumerator())
        {
            int i = 0;

            while (en.MoveNext())
            {
                i++;
                if (i <= number || i >= totalLength - number) 
                     yield return en.Current;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would work but necessarily goes through all the elements in the middle of the top 100 and last 100 and doesnt use optimizations for arrays or lists like native LINQ methods do.

Comment: @T_D What type optimizations are native LINQ methods doing? Could you please, explain.

Comment: After a little research I have to admit I had a wrong impression because some time ago I had a look here: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#q=Enumerable where it is checked if the IEnumerable is a list to do faster indexing but almost all other LINQ methods don't check for stuff like that. Reverse for example does create a buffer of all elements and starts at the end. Although it would be far more easier for a LinkedList for example. So sry for the wrong comment.

Comment: @T_D No problem. I was thinking as you, before reading a book which was speaking about `What does LINQ compiled to in CLR?`. Most LINQ methods  are executing with the `deferred execution` pattern. And the CLR encapsulates the related information, such as the original sequence, predicate, or selector (if any), into an iterator, which will be used when the information is extracted from the original sequence using ToList method or ForEach method or manually using the underlying 
GetEnumerator and MoveNext methods.

Comment: Yeah I understand that concept but I thought it would be more clever ;)